# Como verificar, em meio a um select, existência de relacionamento de um registro de uma tabela A com registros de outras tabelas

Tags: sql-server, join

Já aviso que sou iniciante e talvez esteja perguntado algo simples, mas vamos lá.
 Tenho duas tabelas, PROMOCIONAL e PRODUTOS, sendo que um PRODUTO pode se relacionar com zero ou muitos registros de PROMOCIONAL. O que preciso é de, momento que fizer um select em produto, trazer também a informação de se existe ou não alguma promocional relacionada.
 Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você deseja pode ser realizado com a cláusula `EXISTS`, que significa *EXISTÊNCIA*:

```
SELECT prod.*
  FROM produtos prod
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM promocional promo
               WHERE promo.prod_id = prod.prod_id)
```

> [**`EXISTS`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Quando uma subconsulta é apresentada com a palavra-chave EXISTS, a subconsulta funciona como um teste de existência. A cláusula WHERE da consulta externa testa se as linhas retornadas pela subconsulta existem. A subconsulta não produz de fato nenhum dado; ela retorna um valor TRUE ou FALSE.

Comment: @JoséDiz nessa aqui qual foi o problema pelo qual você deu `downvote`?